# Is there a simpler way to compile this code?

Tags: excel, vba

I've got this macro that copies data from one set of cells to another Sheet.

I've just made it so there's a textbox that pops up if some of the cells are empty and they must be filled in before the macro button accepts and moves all of the fields.

Here it is:

```vb
If ActiveSheet.Range("A2") = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please Fill in More Boxes"
    Exit Sub
End If

If ActiveSheet.Range("B2") = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please Fill in More Boxes"
    Exit Sub
End If

If ActiveSheet.Range("C2") = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please Fill in More Boxes"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Then continues at `D2` before stopping til `H2` and continuing til `O2`.

Is there anyway I can compile it so it's a lot shorter rather than have it multiple times for each individual cell?

I've already tried

```vb
If ActiveSheet.Range("A2:D2","H2:O2") = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please Fill in More Boxes"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
With ActiveSheet
   If .Range("A2") = "" Or .Range("B2") = "" Or .Range("C2") = "" Then 
       MsgBox "Please Fill in More Boxes" 
     Exit Sub 
   End If
end With
```

and a similar block for the other cells further down

Answer (score 2):

Define a range of cells you want to test `TestRange` and then loop through all the cells in that range:

```
Dim TestRange As Range
Set TestRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:D2") 'multiple ranges like "A2:D2,H2:O2"

Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In TestRange
    If Cell.Value = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Please Fill in More Boxes"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next Cell
```

This will avoid extensive use of `Or` like

```
.Range("A2") = "" Or .Range("B2") = "" Or .Range("C2") = ""
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you could use an `OR`

```
If ActiveSheet.Range("A2") = "" Or ActiveSheet.Range("B2") = "" ... Then
```

But you really need to loop through your range

```
Dim c as Range
'For each c in ActiveSheet.Range("A2:D2","H2:O2").Cells (range incorrect)
 For each c in ActiveSheet.Range("A2:D2,H2:O2").Cells '(range corrected)
    If c="" Then 
       MsgBox "Please Fill in More Boxes" 
       Exit Sub 
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Note that `Range("A2:D2","H2:O2")` is the same as `Range("A2:O2")` but the OP probably meant `Range("A2:D2,H2:O2")`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ  Good pickup.  I had missed that!

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim rng As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<- Create a with statement with the sheet name you want. Avoid Activesheet
        'Set the range you want to check
        Set rng = .Range("A2:C2")
        'Loop rnage
        For Each cell In rng
            'If cell is empty
            If cell = "" Then
                'Message box with the cell which is missing
                MsgBox "Please Fill Box " & cell.Address
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next cell

    End With

End Sub
```